# MQTT Listener to listen to a topic and insert data to database on multiple instance pointing to same database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

So I've made a chat application using Java Spring Boot and MQTT. I've made an MQTT listener which listens to all the messages under the `abc` topic (i.e. `abc/#`). For MQTT broker I'm using Amazon MQ.

So what this application does is it listens to all the message and insert the data to the database which is working fine but when I deployed this application on multiple instance I'm facing duplicate data entries because both the instance is pointing to same database which is AWS RDS how to overcome this??

```java
public void subscribe(String topic) throws MqttException {
    logger.info("client connected");

    mqttClient.subscribeWithResponse(topic, (currentTopic, msg) -> {

        logger.info("listened : " + new String(msg.getPayload()));

        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            if (currentTopic.equals("Abc/onlineStatus")) {
                UserOnlineStatusVO userOnlineStatusVO = gson.fromJson(new String(msg.getPayload()), UserOnlineStatusVO.class);
                User user = userRepository.findById(userOnlineStatusVO.getUserId()).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("user does not exist"));
                LocalDateTime lastSeen = LocalDateTime.parse(userOnlineStatusVO.getLastSeen(), format);
                user.setLastSeen(lastSeen);
                user.setOnlineStatus(userOnlineStatusVO.getOnlineStatus());
                userRepository.save(user);
            } else {
                GroupChatMessage groupChatMessage = gson.fromJson(new String(msg.getPayload()), GroupChatMessage.class);
                if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(groupChatMessage.getIsTesting())) {
                    LocalDateTime sendingAt = LocalDateTime.parse(groupChatMessage.getPublishedAt(), sendingAtFormat);
                    groupChatMessage.setSendingAt(sendingAt);
                    groupChatMessageRepository.save(groupChatMessage);
                    logger.info("data inserted : " + groupChatMessage);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So your question is really how to prevent each instance of the client receiving all the massages on a given topic? If so you need to look and see if Amazon MQ supports MQTT shared subscriptions

Comment: Shared subscriptions was added in MQTT 5 and neither ActiveMQ "Classic" nor RabbitMQ (both of which are used by Amazon MQ) supports MQTT 5.

Comment: While formalised in MQTT v5 several brokers had implemented shared subscriptions as a proprietary add on to v3.1.1

Comment: @hardillb, fair enough. Did either ActiveMQ "Classic" or RabbitMQ implement shared subscriptions as a proprietary add on to 3.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the expected behavior. MQTT is fundamentally a pub/sub protocol where **all** the subscribers on a particular topic (or set of topics) get **every** message published to that topic (or set of topics).

I see two ways to tackle the problem of duplicate entries in your database.

1. Make the insertions into the database idempotent.
2. Coordinate each instance of this application so that only one instance is ever active at any point in time.

If you used a broker that supported MQTT 5 (e.g. [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/)) then you could use a "shared" subscription in which case the applications should *share* all the messages published to the topic (or set of topics) and there would be no duplicate consumption or database inserts.